# JavaFX2 - Multiple TabPanes

Tags: javafx-2

I want to do something like that: [image]

So at the left side atm I have in the rootController a ListView

```
 @FXML
 ListView<String> listView;
```

which has two Elements, to stick to the picture let's call them ListElement A and B.

First I added these Elements

```
 ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList("A", "B");
```

Second I add them to the List:

```
   listView.setItems(names);
```

in the start method i call the initRootLayout method

```
void initRootLayout() {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MainDo.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
    try {
        rootLayout = fxmlLoader.load(); // rootLayout == BorderPane
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);

        RootController rootController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**My Problems:**

1. If I start my application it loads the everything fine, except the fact that the content of the list is not shown. It looks like that:

[image: https://ibb.co/f16JMF]

2. If i fix that Problem, I am looking for the feature that A and B have a different fix Tab Pane. So if I am clicking on A and B was shown before, another Tab Pane is shown where i can show different content. So if i have n Elements in the List, I also have n Tab panes.

Can someone please help me here? I tried that already the last 8 hours with zero success.

Thanks

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GsdaZWDcdY) helped me a lot when I was first experimenting with JavaFX. It shows a very simple way to transition between screens. Once you master this, you see many limitations, and it is time to move to a dependency injection framework like Adam Bein's [AfterburnerFX](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/). This is much more powerful, and once you get used to the conventions, is very easy to implement.

Comment: Regarding your list items, I don't see where you are loading the items in the `ListView` in your code, so it is very difficult to determine your issue. I suspect you're instantiating it with `listView = new ListView()` before calling `initRootLayout()`, and then when you call `FXMLLoader.load()` it is reinstantiating it, causing your changes to be lost. You should add your items after the call to `FXMLLoader.load()`.